# Relation between two terms having complex variables, functions, and partial derivatives

Tags: complex-analysis

This problem has been racking my brain for days and I'm having a hard time trying to find resources on how to move forward. Basically I'm given two expression of the form

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{\frac{\partial f(z_1)}{\partial z_1}} \frac{f(z_1)}{z_1} \quad ,\quad \displaystyle \frac{1}{\frac{\partial f(z_2)}{\partial z_2}} \frac{f(z_2)}{z_2}$

where $z_1$ and $z_2$ are complex numbers. I need to understand how their **sum** behaves to further my analysis. I have determined that $f(z_2) = -(f(z_1))^*$ and $z_2 = -z_1^*$ where the star `*` denotes the complex conjugate.

Making the corresponding substitutions into the second expression, it is rewritten as

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{\frac{\partial -(f(z_1))^*}{\partial -z_1^*}} \frac{-(f(z_1))^*}{-z_1^*}$

My first question is on the treatment of the negative signs in the partial derivative. I'm pretty sure I can pull the negative sign out of the operand since it's basically a constant, -1, but I don't know if I can do that with the operator, $\frac{\partial}{\partial -z_1^*} = -\frac{\partial}{\partial z_1^*}$? Assuming I can pull out the negative signs, I now have the following for the second expression

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{\frac{\partial (f(z_1))^*}{\partial z_1^*}} \frac{(f(z_1))^*}{z_1^*}$

The original two expressions are rewritten here, with an update of the second expression

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{\frac{\partial f(z_1)}{\partial z_1}} \frac{f(z_1)}{z_1} \quad ,\quad \frac{1}{\frac{\partial (f(z_1))^*}{\partial z_1^*}} \frac{(f(z_1))^*}{z_1^*}$

I'm going express the first term as $w = \frac{1}{\frac{\partial f(z_1)}{\partial z_1}} \frac{f(z_1)}{z_1}$. If the second term is the conjugate (i.e. $w^*$), and I then add them together, $w+w^* = 2 \Re(w)$, the sum solution becomes

$\displaystyle 2\Re\left(\frac{1}{\frac{\partial f(z_1)}{\partial z_1}} \frac{f(z_1)}{z_1}\right)$

OK, I've made two assumptions to reach this point

1. $\frac{\partial}{\partial -z_1^*} = -\frac{\partial}{\partial z_1^*}$
2. $\left(\frac{\partial (f(z_1))}{\partial z_1}\right)^* = \frac{\partial (f(z_1))^*}{\partial z_1^*}$

I'm looking for insights on these assumptions. Also I never mentioned it, but I'm sure the nature of $f()$ is important. Can you comment on how the solution would be altered if $f()$ were real or if it were complex. I have both cases, but this is where I'll be moving forward to next.

Comment: You would need $f(z)=-f(-z^*)^*$ in some neighborhood of $z_1$ and $z_2=-z_1^*$, that it is true accidentally in one point is not sufficient.

Comment: Maybe I'm miss interpreting your comment, but I'm not trying to prove the general statement, $f(z)=-f(-z^*)^*$. It's just something I observe in my particular problem where $z_2=-z_1^*$. I'm starting with this observation, then performing an analysis on the sum of the expressions. Can you comment further on the questions I present in post?

Comment: I think I should have split this question into multiple ones so that I can better follow the response of others. @LutzL can you tell me where your comment applies so I can better understand. In other words, what did I say/do wrong that lead you to make that comment?

Comment: You would need this to conclude on the behavior of the derivatives. Just getting the equality of two function values is not enough for that..